# new document dialog showing master page header images

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, document-library, master-page

I have a team site and I made some changes in master page as below:

1. Moved top menu links and search box below page heading
2. In place of top links I placed an image called **image1** and in place of search box I placed another image called **image2**
3. Replacing SharePoint logo with my own logo and increasing its size

I did all this using DIV/CSS. Now I am no designer, not even close. So I had to do a lot of trial and error before every thing looked ok except this one issue which now I am facing and i.e. when you click on "new document" link which opens a dialog box where you can upload document, that window is also showing those logos (which I mentioned in point 2 above)

How can I get rid of that? I was thinking that if somehow I can find out if the dialog is open then I can hide those images using CSS/Jquery?

Here's partial code to given you and understanding where I have wrote code. My divs are named "mydiv" and "mydiv2" while rest of the code is SharePoint's default:

```
<div id="WebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel
        ID="WebPartAdderUpdatePanel"
        UpdateMode="Conditional"
        ChildrenAsTriggers="false"
        runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <WebPartPages:WebPartAdder ID="WebPartAdder" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="s4-workspace" class="ms-core-overlay">
<div id="mydiv" style="float:left;border:thin;border-style:none;width:210px;position:absolute; padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:200px;z-index:1;">
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" width="65%" height="65%"></div>
<div id="mydiv2" style="border: thin none currentColor; width: 250px; right:600px;position:absolute; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:10px;float: right;z-index:1;">
<img src="/images/image2.jpg" width="800" height="56">
</div>

        <div id="s4-bodyContainer">

        <div id="s4-titlerow"
            class="ms-dialogHidden s4-titlerowhidetitle">

        <div id="titleAreaBox"
            class="ms-noList ms-table ms-core-tableNoSpace">
        <div id="titleAreaRow"
            class="ms-tableRow">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the CSS class `ms-dialogHidden` to any custom elements to prevent them from being shown in dialogs.

Here is a [blog post](http://ericoverfield.com/sharepoint-2013-tricks-hide-elements-in-dialogs/) about it.

Comment: It's perfect...